# swift typecasting performance cost

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, casting

I am trying to keep my `func update:currentTime` as fast as possible. This function was overridden from the `SKScene` class and gets called around 2000 to 4000 times a second. I want to loop through all the scene's children and do an optional typecast to see if a child implements my [Observer](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer) interface and then call update on that. Note: I make reference to two separate `func update` methods here.

Will my performance be shot if I typecast 4000 times a second? **More importantly, how expensive is a typecast in Swift?**

Code for context:

```
// Called inside func update:currentTime
let children = self.children
    for child in children {
        if let observer = child as? TimerObserver {
            observer.update()
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: The only real answer is to use Instruments and actually measure it. And it needs to be measured on a release build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. Casting from e.g. `int` to `float` will cost as the compiler will create real code to convert the one into the other.

In contrast an object type cast is at no cost. It's just that eventually a method call will fail as the cast type is not what you tell it should be. It's just that you pretend the object pointer will point to some legal object. The pointer itself is not changed.

Comment: I don't understand, if a cast can fail then how does it have no performance impact? Is there not any type checking involved?

Comment: A cast failure due to programmer error would not be cast. The question WRT performance is is it really a cast or creating a new representation as an int to a float or even a short to a long. One has a run-time cost the other does not, it is just looking at things differently. The problem goes back at least to the "C" language where both actual conversions as well as true casts were both named casts.

Comment: Correct. The type checking (for legal methods) is done in case of an object in either case. So no difference in performance.

Comment: In Swift a cast usually has to go through fairly involved runtime machinery to check types, which is not at all free.